# Writing a function in R to plot ROC curve using pROC

Tags: r, function, rstudio, proc

I'm trying to write a function to plot ROC curves based on different scoring systems I have to predict an outcome.

I have a dataframe data_all, with columns "score_1" and "Threshold.2000". I generate a ROC curve as desired with the following:

```
plot.roc(data_all$Threshold.2000, data_all$score_1)
```

My goal is to generate a ROC curve for a number of different outcomes (e.g. Threshold.1000) and scores (score_1, score_2 etc), but am initially trying to set it up just for different scores. My function is as follows:

```
roc_plot <- function(dataframe_of_interest, score_of_interest) {
plot.roc(dataframe_of_interest$Threshold.2000, dataframe_of_interest$score_of_interest)}
```

> I get the following error: Error in roc.default(x, predictor, plot =
>   TRUE, ...) : No valid data provided.

I'd be very grateful if someone can spot why my function doesn't work! I'm a python coder and new-ish to R, and haven't had much luck trying a number of different things. Thanks very much.

EDIT:
Here is the same example with mtcars so it's reproducible:

```
data(mtcars)
plot.roc(mtcars$vs, mtcars$mpg) # --> makes correct graph
roc_plot <- function(dataframe_of_interest, score_of_interest) {
plot.roc(dataframe_of_interest$mpg, dataframe_of_interest$score_of_interest)}
```

Outcome: 
Error in roc.default(x, predictor, plot = TRUE, ...) : No valid data provided.
roc_plot(mtcars, vs)

Comment: please provide a sample of your data, since the error is based on your data. You can use `head()` or `dput()` for this. If you are not allowed to share the data, try to reproduce your error with a basic dataset like mtcars

Comment: Thank you, I have edited it to include mtcars as the example

Comment: this is a fundamental  understanding problem. A function is declared like this: `roc_plot <- function(x, y) {plot.roc(x, y)}` and then you fill the `x,y` when you call it: `roc_plot(mtcars$vs, mtcars$mpg)`. Actually it's the same as in python. When you use the $ you try to call the column name of the dataframe. Also if you want to ALWAYS call the same column, you can do it by filtering.

Comment: When you want to always call the same columns: `roc_plot <- function(dataframe_of_interest, score_of_interest) {
  plot.roc(dataframe_of_interest$vs, dataframe_of_interest$mpg)}
roc_plot(mtcars, mtcars)` please be aware, you used the wrong variable names in your `mtcars` example. You changed the first call to `$mpg$` but the second is still `score_of_interest`, since there is not such a column, you get the error

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution that works as desired (i.e. lets the user specify different values for `score_of_interest`):

```
library(pROC)
data(mtcars)

plot.roc(mtcars$vs, mtcars$mpg) # --> makes correct graph

# expects `score_of_interest` to be a string!!!
roc_plot <- function(dataframe_of_interest, score_of_interest) {
    plot.roc(dataframe_of_interest$vs, dataframe_of_interest[, score_of_interest])
}

roc_plot(mtcars, 'mpg')
roc_plot(mtcars, 'cyl')
```

Note that your error was not resulting from an incorrect column name, it was resulting from an incorrect use of the `data.frame` class.  Notice what happens with a simpler function:

```
foo <- function(x, col_name) {
    head(x$col_name)
}
foo(mtcars, mpg)
## NULL
```

This returns `NULL`. So in your original function when you tried to supply `plot.roc` with `dataframe_of_interest$score_of_interest` you were actually feeding `plot.roc` a `NULL`.

There are several ways to extract a column from a `data.frame` by the column name when that name is stored in an object (which is what you're doing when you pass it as an argument in a function). Perhaps the easiest way is to remember that a `data.frame` is like a 2D array-type object and so we can use familiar `object[i, j]` syntax, but we ask for all rows and we specify the column by name, e.g., `mtcars[, 'mpg']`.  This still works if we assign the string `'mpg'` to an object:

```
x <- 'mpg'
mtcars[, x]
```

So that's how I produced my solution.  Going a step further, it's not hard to imagine how you would be able to supply both a `score_of_interest` and a `threshold_of_interest`:

```
roc_plot2 <- function(dataframe_of_interest, threshold_of_interest, score_of_interest) {
    plot.roc(dataframe_of_interest[, threshold_of_interest], 
             dataframe_of_interest[, score_of_interest])
}

roc_plot2(mtcars, 'vs', 'mpg')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is extremely helpful!